# Kotlin: Split Sequence<T> by N items into Sequence<Sequence<T>>?

Tags: kotlin, sequence, chunked, batching

How to "take(N)" iteratively - get a Sequence<Sequence>, each inner sequences having next N elements?

I am writing a high-load application in Kotlin.

I have tens of thousands of entries to insert to a database.
I want to batch them by, say, 1000.

So I created a loop:

```
    val itemsSeq = itemsList.iterator().asSequence()
    while (true) {
        log.debug("Taking $BATCH_SIZE from $itemsSeq")
        val batchSeq = itemsSeq.take(BATCH_SIZE)
        val squareBatch = applySomething(batchSeq, something)
            ?: break
    }

    fun applySomething(batch: Sequence<Item>, something: Something) {
        /* Fully consumes batch. Bulk-loads from DB by IDs, applies, bulk-saves. */ 
    }
```

I thought that `take()` would advance the `itemsSeq` and the next call to `take()` would give me a sequence "view" of `itemsSeq` starting at the 10th item.

But with this code, I am getting:

```
DEBUG Taking 10 from kotlin.sequences.ConstrainedOnceSequence@53fe15ff
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: This sequence can be consumed only once.
    at kotlin.sequences.ConstrainedOnceSequence.iterator(SequencesJVM.kt:23)
    at kotlin.sequences.TakeSequence$iterator$1.<init>(Sequences.kt:411)
    at kotlin.sequences.TakeSequence.iterator(Sequences.kt:409)
```

So it seems that the `take()` "opens" the `itemsSeq` again, while that can be consumed only once.

As a workaround, I can use `chunked()`:

```
public fun <T> Sequence<T>.chunked(size: Int): Sequence<List<T>> {
```

But I would prefer not to create `List`s, rather `Sequence`s.
**What I am looking for is something between `take()` and `chunked()`.**

Is there anything such in Kotlin SDK?
I can possibly create my own `sequence { ... }` but for readability, I would prefer something built-in.

Comment: What is the declaration of `applySomething`?

Comment: Added to the Q. `fun applySomething(batch: Sequence<Item>, something: Something)`

Comment: What does it do to `batch`? Does it consume `batch`? I'm asking because `take` doesn't consume `batch`, so it could only be something in `applySomething`.

Comment: How can you use the batch in "bulk" without using some sort of collection representing the batch at some point? It seems to me that wanting to avoid creating a list for each batch is just postponing the problem to `applySomething`. That's why I would say `chunked()` is the way to go. But I'd be curious to see the exact code of `applySomething` too.

Comment: @Joffrey, the purpose is not to break the Sequence chain. The `applySomething` can be parallelized, for which I would again convert the `List` to a  `Sequence` and split it. And why move around a list of thousands of items when I don't need to.

Comment: You were mentioning doing a bulk action in DB, in which case you do need a collection. But if `applySomething` splits again the sequence, what's the point in batching in the first place? At some point you'll reach the point where you process the items in an actual batch collection - that's the only place where batching has an effect, and thus the only place where you should batch. And at that point `chunked` would be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to construct a Sequence by handing it over an Iterator, see [Sequence](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/-sequence.html).

> Given an iterator function constructs a Sequence that returns values
> through the Iterator provided by that function. The values are
> evaluated lazily, and the sequence is potentially infinite.

Wrapped in an extension function it could look like this:

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.toValuesThroughIteratorSequence(): Sequence<T> {
  val iterator = this.iterator()
  return Sequence { iterator }
}
```

Quick test:

```
data class Test(val id: Int)

val itemsList = List(45) { Test(it) }
val batchSize = 10

val repetitions = itemsList.size.div(batchSize) + 1
val itemsSeq = itemsList.toValuesThroughIteratorSequence()

(0 until repetitions).forEach { index ->
  val batchSeq = itemsSeq.take(batchSize)
  println("Batch no. $index:   " + batchSeq.map { it.id.toString().padStart(2, ' ') }.joinToString(" "))
}
```

Output:

```
Batch no. 0:    0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
Batch no. 1:   10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
Batch no. 2:   20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
Batch no. 3:   30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39
Batch no. 4:   40 41 42 43 44
```

Comment: I think it would be useful to mention one thing here. What you did is actually OP's initial attempt. The only difference is that they used `Iterator.asSequence()` which is implemented as: `Sequence { this }.constrainOnce()`. So this `constrainOnce()` is exactly the thing OP wanted to avoid :-) Otherwise, OP's attempt was perfectly fine.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder why the Kotlin authors added `constrainOnce()`. Probably as a safety measure. Or to keep the semantics of `Iterator`.

Comment: @OndraŽižka I would assume that is not a safety measure, but a main piece of the implementation. Without it a that specific sequence could be consumed more than once. See https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/constrain-once.html. Sequences are not per se once-constrained. Hence broot's comment.

Comment: @OndraŽižka I believe the "default" meaning of sequences is that they are... well, sequences of some elements. They are not "live" iterations over something, but are like collections, only lazy and potentially unbound. So in most cases it makes more sense than subsequent calls of `sequence.take()` will provide exactly the same elements, similarly as calls to `list.take()` always return the same. If you  create a sequence from iterable or with `sequence {}`, then each `take()` will restart iteration. We can't do this when creating a sequence from iterator, so it is restricted to single use.

Comment: In other words: sequence created with `Sequence { iterator }` and without `constrainOnce()` is not really a valid sequence. It doesn't behave like sequences, it is some kind of a hack. Although, in your case maybe it is justified, because stdlib provides nice utils like `TakeSequence`, but it doesn't provide similar tools for iterators, so you would have to implement them by yourself.

Comment: @broot I am curious: why do you consider such a sequence not to be 'really a valid sequence'?

Comment: Because it changes its contents with each use. See documentation for sequences - they are compared many times to iterables, not to iterators. If we have a `fibonacciSequence` created using `sequence {}` and we use `take()` multiple times on the same object, then each call means: "take first 5 numbers of fibonacci sequence", "Now, take first 10 numbers of fibonacci sequence". `take()` doesn't mean: "Take next 10 numbers from where we left". `fibonacciSequence()` in this case is a "constant" sequence of some items, each time exactly the same items.

Comment: All standard ways of creating sequences work this way: `sequence {}`, `sequenceOf()`, `Iterable.asSequence()`, `Iterator.asSequence()`. The last one is even intentionally protected against working in a different way. Sequence created with `Sequence { iterator }` is conceptually still pretty much an iterator, but on steroids ;-)

Comment: @broot Yes, I understand the semantics of _take()_.

Comment: The difference lies in holding a reference from the outside to the iterator: _val itemsSeq = itemsList.iterator().let { Sequence { it } }_ vs
_val itemsSeq = Sequence { itemsList.iterator() }_.

Comment: These two code samples produce sequences that behave much differently. The second will create new iterator each time you call `take()` on it, always starting from the beginning of a list. The fist will re-use the same iterator with each `take()`, so it will take next items.

Comment: @broot Yes, exactly

Answer (score 3):

### Background

First of all, we need to be aware there is a big difference between an object that we can iterate over and object that represents a "live" or already running iteration process. First group means `Iterable` (so `List`, `Set` and all other collections), `Array`, `Flow`, etc. Second group is mostly `Iterator` or old Java `Enumeration`. The difference could be also compared to file vs file pointer when reading or database table vs database cursor.

**`Sequence` belongs to the first group**. Sequence object does not represent a live, already started iteration, but just a set of elements. These elements can be produced lazily, sequence could have unbounded size and usually internally it works by using iterators, but conceptually sequence is not an iterator itself.

If we look into the [documentation about sequences](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sequences.html) it clearly compares them to `Iterable`, not to `Iterator`. All standard ways to construct sequences like: `sequenceOf()`, `sequence {}`, `Iterable.asSequence()` produce sequences that return the same list of items every time we iterate over them. `Iterator.asSequence()` also follows this pattern, but because it can't re-produce same items twice, it is intentionally protected against iterating multiple times:

```kotlin
public fun <T> Iterator<T>.asSequence(): Sequence<T> = Sequence { this }.constrainOnce()
```

### Problem

Your initial attempt with using `take()` didn't work, because this is a misuse of sequences. We expect that subsequent `take()` calls on the same sequence object will produce exactly the same items (usually), not next items. Similarly as we expect multiple `take()` calls on a list always produce same items, each time starting from the beginning.

Being more specific, your error was caused by above `constrainOnce()`. When we invoke `take()` multiple times on a sequence, it has to restart from the beginning, but it can't do this if it was created from an iterator, so `Iterator.asSequence()` explicitly disallows this.

### Simple solution

To fix the problem, you can just skip `constrainOnce()` part, as suggested by @lukas.j. This solution is nice, because stdlib already provides tools like `Sequence.take()`, so if used carefully, this is the easiest to implement and it just works.

However, I personally consider this a kind of workaround, because the resulting sequence doesn't behave as sequences do. It is more like an iterator on steroids than a real sequence. You need to be careful when using this sequence with existing operators or 3rd party code, because such sequence may work differently than they expect and as a result, you may get incorrect results.

### Advanced solution

We can follow your initial attempt of using subsequent `take()` calls. In this case our object is used for live iteration, so it is no longer a proper sequence, but rather an iterator. The only thing we miss in stdlib is a way to create a sub-iterator with a single chunk. We can implement it by ourselves:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val list = (0 .. 25).toList()

    val iter = list.iterator()
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        val chunk = iter.limited(10)
        println(chunk.asSequence().toList())
    }
}

fun <T> Iterator<T>.limited(n: Int): Iterator<T> = object : Iterator<T> {
    var left = n
    val iterator = this@limited

    override fun next(): T {
        if (left == 0)
            throw NoSuchElementException()
        left--
        return iterator.next()
    }

    override fun hasNext(): Boolean {
        return left > 0 && iterator.hasNext()
    }
}
```

I named it `limited()`, because `take()` suggests we read items from the iterator. Instead, we only create another iterator on top of the provided iterator.

Of course, sequences are easier to use than iterators and typical solution to this problem is by using `chunked()`. With above `limited()` it is pretty straightforward to implement `chunkedAsSequences()`:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val list = (0 .. 25).toList()

    list.asSequence()
        .chunkedAsSequences(10)
        .forEach { println(it.toList()) }
}

fun <T> Sequence<T>.chunkedAsSequences(size: Int): Sequence<Sequence<T>> = sequence {
    val iter = iterator()
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        val chunk = iter.limited(size)
        yield(chunk.asSequence())
        chunk.forEach {} // required if chunk was not fully consumed
    }
}
```

Please also note there is a tricky case of chunk being not fully consumed. `chunkedAsSequences()` is protected against this scenario. Previous simpler solutions aren't.

Comment: Great, thanks! I did not think of solving that at the Iterator level. I will try that.

Comment: BWT. Kotlin stdlib is consistently well named, but here, the `chunked()` should have been `chunk()` as it is a terminal operation;   `chunked()` would IMHO be more suitable for this kind of adjustment to the underlying.